# (x,y) co-ordinates of n equally spaced points on the perimeter of a square

Tags: linear-algebra

Where a square of known dimensions has `n` points equally spaced around its perimeter, is there a way to calculate the set of `(x,y)` coordinates of these points?

I have a solution in C# language where starting from `(0,0)` I can add increments of `perimeter/n` to the `x` coordinate up to the max allowed value for `x` (i.e the length of the side of the square), and then spill the remainder into y and so on, but I can't help thinking there must be a better way.

**Update with an example:**
For instance, with number of points `n=9` and the square sides of `length=2`, the distance between each pair of points around the perimeter is `0.889` and the set of points to two decimal places would be:

```
(0, 0)
(0.89, 0)
(1.78, 0)
(2, 0.67)
(2, 1.56)
(1.56, 2)
(0.67, 2)
(0, 1.78)
(0, 0.89)
```

Comment: If the square is 2 units on each side, with the lower left corner at (0,0), and $n=9$, please specify explicitly what the coordinates of these 9 points would be.  I need this info to respond to your question.  Also, please address your comment to @user2661923 so that I will be notified of a response.

Comment: @user2661923 I've added the example you requested to the question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that each side of the square is $s$ units and that you are going to have $n$ points.

First, **pretend** that instead of placing these points around the perimeter of a square, you are placing them on 1 line segment, of length $4s$.  Then the $n$ points would be located at

$$0, ~\left(1 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
 ~\left(2 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
 ~\left(3 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
\cdots,
 ~\left((n-1) \times \frac{4s}{n}\right).$$

These one dimensional locations must then be translated into points on the perimeter of your square.

Let $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots\},$ where
$k = \lfloor \frac{n}{4}\rfloor.$ 
That is, $k$ is the largest non-negative integer less than or equal to $\frac{n}{4}.$

First, one point goes to $(0,0)$.
Then, you can distribute $k$ points along the bottom edge of the rectangle, at points

$$\left(1 \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~0\right),
 ~\left(2 \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~0\right),
 ~\left(3 \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~0\right),
\cdots,
 ~\left(k \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~0\right).
$$

Similarly, you can then distribute another $k$ points along the left edge at

$$\left(0, ~1 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
 ~\left(0, ~2 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
 ~\left(0, ~3 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
\cdots,
 ~\left(0, ~k \times \frac{4s}{n}\right).
$$

Now, you have to "*turn the corners*".

First, calculate the "margin left over" along the bottom edge as

$$M = \left[s - \left(k \times \frac{4s}{n}\right)\right].$$

Then, the $k$ points along the right edge will be located at

$$\left(s, ~-M + 1 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
 ~\left(s, ~-M + 2 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
 ~\left(s, ~-M + 3 \times \frac{4s}{n}\right),
\cdots,
 ~\left(s, ~-M + k \times \frac{4s}{n}\right).
$$

Similarly, the $k$ points along the top edge will go at

$$\left(-M + 1 \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~s\right),
 ~\left(-M + 2 \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~s\right),
 ~\left(-M + 3 \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~s\right),
\cdots,
 ~\left(-M + k \times \frac{4s}{n}, ~s\right).
$$

Note that when $n$ is a multiple of $4$, so that $4k$ exactly equals $n$, then the above algorithm will end up having you place a point on the upper right corner of the square **twice.**

There is an exceptional case to be considered.

If

$$s + M ~\geq~ \left(k+1\right) 
\times \left(\frac{4s}{n}\right)$$

then an additional point will need to be placed along both the right edge, and the top edge.